# pass function args through to next function - python

Tags: python, argv, keyword-argument

I'm trying to make a simple logger function (I'm not a python expert):

```py
def logger(*argv):
  print(argv)
```

`log('Ok', 'this', 'is', 'a', 'log')`

**Current output**: `('Ok', 'this', 'is', 'a', 'log')`

**Desired output:** `Ok this is a log`

How can I format the argv to just pass the log through?

Comment: Does ```print(*argv)``` work

Comment: Assuming `argv` is `sys.argv` and you're talking about parameters passed on the command line, each of those words is its own argument. If you want to join them, join them: `" ".join(argv)`.